# How would I change my imageView src with one button but, a few images at random?

Tags: android, random, imageview

I want to make a simple app (in Android studio) that can change the image with one button and every button press a different images goes on top of it at random. I only know how to change one photo with only one button with this code

```
thatImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

But I don't know how to have multiple images ready to replace it when the user presses the button and a random. So if anyone can help me out with this I would appreciate it and thank you for the support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an array of images, and then use random number to get one of them:

```
 int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2...};

 Random random = new Random();

 Integer rand = random.nextInt(myImageList.length - 1) + 0;

 thatImage.setImageResource(myImageList[rand]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings.xml

```
<array name="myImages">
   <item>@drawable/a</item>
   <item>@drawable/b</item>
   <item>@drawable/c</item>
   <item>@drawable/d</item>
   <item>@drawable/e</item>
</array>
```

for the main activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
    Resources res = getResources();
    final TypedArray myImages = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.myImages);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Random random = new Random();
            int randomInt = random.nextInt(myImages.length());
            int drawableID = myImages.getResourceId(randomInt, -1);
            background.setBackgroundResource(drawableID);

        }
    });

}
```